# How to tell dart to not convert map to <String, String> type and let it be <String, Object> type?

Tags: flutter, dart, hashmap

I have some data which initially is `List<Map<String, String>>` but in future in some methods calls I have to assign those `Map<String, String>` elements an `<String, dynamic>` values. Here is some dart code that shows my intention :

```
class MyClass {
  String ageGroup = 'some';
  MyClass({required this.ageGroup});
}

void main() {
  var data = [
    {
      'name': 'john',
      'userName': 'john',
    },
    {
      'name': 'john1',
      'userName': 'john1',
    },
  ];

  // JsLinkedHashMap<String, String> in dartpad
  print(data[0].runtimeType);
  
  // after some while
  // throws an error
  data[0]['ageGroup'] = MyClass(ageGroup: 'something');
}
```

`data[0]['ageGroup']` assignment gives me error like this : `Error: A value of type 'MyClass' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.`

How should I let know dart that don't convert this maps to `<String, String>` and let it be `<String, dynamic>` as in future `Objects` would be the values too.

I have found 1 workaround but I don't want to use it :

```
void main() {
  var data = [
    {
      'something_random': 123,
      'name': 'john',
      'userName': 'john',
    },
    {
      'something_random': 123,
      'name': 'john1',
      'userName': 'john1',
    },
  ];
  
  print(data[0].runtimeType);
  
  data[0]['ageGroup'] = MyClass(ageGroup: 'something');
}
```

This works well but I don't want to use it like this....are there any other ways...
I have tried `.cast<>()` and another type castings but still of no use.

Comment: instead of ```var data = ``` use ```List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = ``` when declaring the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Dart infers the type of you `data` literal map.

In your first example there is only String as values so it infers the type `List<Map<String, String>>`. In the last snippet it infers `List<Map<String, Object>>` because there are Strings and ints in values of maps.

You can force the type of data by 2 ways:

```dart
var data = <Map<String, dynamic>>[...]; // force type of list literal

// or

List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [...]; // directly type data
```